# on hover show only in one element but not in all

Tags: jquery-hover

I have multiple div elements and I wanted to add one function on hover but now show on all div elements.

How to set just only for one element at mouse hover. Thank you in advance for the help

```
$('.box .line').hide();
// toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
$('.box > div').hover(function() {
$('.box .line').toggle('fast');
return false;
```

});

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box > div').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.line').toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Probably incorrectly explained. i have 10 box in all boxes is one element hiden (.line). When i hover on one box appears to me in all 10 boxes, but i wont to shown in the following box but not in all.

Comment: Now working, it was a small error which noticed later. thanks for help.